# Can I grow the length of an object by tweening?

Tags: createjs, tween

With createjs.Tween, is it possible to grow an object by pinning one end and extending the other rather than just moving it? For example, like Pinocchio's nose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is definitely possible.

First you will want to set the point to scale from, with regX and regY. (in this case we set it to the middle left border)

```
displayObject.regX = 0;
displayObject.regY = displayObject.getBounds().height / 2;
```

You can then tween the scaleX or scaleY properties to stretch the graphic.

```
createjs.Tween.get(displayObject).to({scaleX:2});
```

Comment: I created a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dwwaddell/Bpz88/878/#&togetherjs=1hDzj30RHh

Comment: When you add a value (other than 0) to regX (regY), it is like moving it left (up) by that value rather than pinning it. When you scaleX in the tween, it does nothing.

Comment: First, the link to TweenJS in your jsfiddle was invalid. Second, regX and regY are not percentages, they are coordinates. You wouldn't use .5 for half of the width of a displayobject, you would use the actual width divided by 2.